# Is it possible to save multi ring polygons to the ArcGIS server REST API?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api

I'm trying to insert new polygons that the user has drawn through the addFeatures REST endpoint and I'm getting an error when the user draws a bow-tie and tries to insert it.  Is this simply not supported or am I missing some geoprocessing step?

Comment: A little help please?  Post points list going to the server.  Please post error returned by the server and error code

Comment: Did you try passing it to the [simplify method on the geometry service first](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/rest/apiref/simplify.html)?

Comment: +1 for Kirks comments.  This is one of our test cases and it works.  If Kirk doesnt put together an answer by new year, ill put an answer down with some evidence.

Comment: Sending the graphic to the simplify method is how I'm getting multiple rings.  On the client after it is drawn, I have one ring that just happens to cross itself. The Silverlight Map control handles this fine.  For now my solution is to just tell the user not to let the polygon edges cross.

Comment: Geometries are being stored in a SQL Server 2008 Geometry datatype.